# How to give weight to result which contains repeated words in hibernate search

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I am using hibernate search with combination of different queries like keyword, phrase, fuzzy etc. It is working as expected. The only thing i cannot recognize is how to give higher weight to a result which contains repeated words.
For exp.
I have 3 index

1. "word"
2. "word word"
3. "word word word"

Now if I provide search keyword "word" it should return index 3 with higher weight then index 2 and then index 1 with lower weight.
I googled a lot but couldn't find anything. Can we do this using hibernate search?

Comment: are you looking for the count, from DB our want some manipulation logic in java

Comment: I am looking for something which will increase lucene score of the result which contains multiple search keywords using hibernate-search